# Adding an XML Processing Instruction just before the element if there are only one or zero (empty) elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I had the following xml,

```
  <Standards xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
    <Standard>
        <ProductID>200057</ProductID>
        <Prefix>ISO</Prefix>
        <SNumber>1001</SNumber>
        <Year>1986</Year>
        <Designation>ISO 1001:1986</Designation>
        <Publisher>ISO</Publisher>
        <ProductDescriptions>
            <ProductDescription>
                <LanguageCode>en</LanguageCode>
                <DescriptionID>372980</DescriptionID>
            </ProductDescription>
            <ProductDescription>
                <LanguageCode>fr</LanguageCode>
                <DescriptionID>1878599</DescriptionID>
            </ProductDescription>
        </ProductDescriptions>
        <IndustryCodes/>
        <ProductAttributes/>
        <ProductReconfirmationNotices/>
    </Standard>
</Standards>
```

And wanted to transform it into the following format.

```
<Standards xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
    <Standard>
        <ProductID>200057</ProductID>
        <Prefix>ISO</Prefix>
        <SNumber>1001</SNumber>
        <Year>1986</Year>
        <Designation>ISO 1001:1986</Designation>
        <Publisher>ISO</Publisher>
        <ProductDescriptions>
            <LanguageCode>en</LanguageCode>
            <DescriptionID>372980</DescriptionID>
        </ProductDescriptions>
        <ProductDescriptions>
            <LanguageCode>fr</LanguageCode>
            <DescriptionID>1878599</DescriptionID>
        </ProductDescriptions>
        <IndustryCodes/>
        <ProductAttributes/>
    </Standard>
</Standards>
```

I was able to do it using the following xslt template matches. What is does is take all the elements which has ProductDescription or IndustryCode or ProductAttribute or SaleItem or SaleItemAttribute etc as a child and replace it with it's parent element name in source xml.

```
  <xsl:template
        match="*[x:ProductDescription]|*[x:IndustryCode]|*[x:ProductAttribute]|*[x:SaleItem]|*[x:SaleItemAttribute]|*[x:SaleItemfile]|*[x:SaleItemPrice]">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- Replace "item" with its parent in source XML -->
    <xsl:template
        match="x:ProductDescription|x:IndustryCode|x:ProductAttribute|x:SaleItem|x:SaleItemAttribute|x:SaleItemfile|x:SaleItemPrice">
        <xsl:element name="{name(..)}">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
```

But now I need to add an XML Processing Instruction and resulting xml should be like this. I just need to add the PI just before the first occurrence of these element if there are many such elements such as ProductDescription here. Also I need to add the same PI if there is no element (i.e. empty element) such as IndustryCodes or even there is only one single element such as Standard.

```
<Standards xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
    <?xml-multiple ?>
    <Standard>
        <ProductID>200057</ProductID>
        <Prefix>ISO</Prefix>
        <SNumber>1001</SNumber>
        <Year>1986</Year>
        <Designation>ISO 1001:1986</Designation>
        <Publisher>ISO</Publisher>
        <?xml-multiple ?>
        <ProductDescriptions>
            <LanguageCode>en</LanguageCode>
            <DescriptionID>372980</DescriptionID>
        </ProductDescriptions>
        <ProductDescriptions>
            <LanguageCode>fr</LanguageCode>
            <DescriptionID>1878599</DescriptionID>
        </ProductDescriptions>
        <?xml-multiple ?>
        <IndustryCodes/>
        <?xml-multiple ?>
        <ProductAttributes/>
    </Standard>
</Standards>
```

XML Processing Instruction (PI) can be added as follows in xslt.

```
<xsl:processing-instruction name="xml-multiple"/>
```

How can I change the above template to get this thing done. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That's a terrible use of processing instructions.  For sure not "standard" if that matters to you.

Comment: I changed my xslt template as follows.  <xsl:template
  match="*[x:ProductDescription]|*[x:IndustryCode]|*[x:ProductAttribute]|*[x:SaleItem]|*[x:SaleItemAttribute]|*[x:SaleItemfile]|*[x:SaleItemPrice]">
  <xsl:processing-instruction name="xml-multiple" />
  <xsl:apply-templates />
 </xsl:template> Then it gives me the PI before all the elements which are not empty. But how can I do this for empty elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For you existing template, that replaces the parent element, you can just add in the instruction directly

```
<xsl:template
    match="*[x:ProductDescription]|*[x:IndustryCode]|*[x:ProductAttribute]|*[x:SaleItem]|*[x:SaleItemAttribute]|*[x:SaleItemfile]|*[x:SaleItemPrice]">
    <xsl:processing-instruction name="xml-multiple"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

You would then need a separate template to handle empty elements

```
<xsl:template
    match="x:ProductDescriptions|x:IndustryCodes|x:ProductAttributes|x:SaleItems|x:SaleItemAttributes|x:SaleItemfiles|x:SaleItemPrices">
    <xsl:processing-instruction name="xml-multiple"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Note how you don't need to check if they have child elements or not. Because the other template matches them when they do have children, that will be used due to it having a higher priority (because it has a conditional check).

You could add the `Standard` element to this list too.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:x="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template
        match="x:Standard|x:ProductDescriptions|x:IndustryCodes|x:ProductAttributes|x:SaleItems|x:SaleItemAttributes|x:SaleItemfiles|x:SaleItemPrices">
        <xsl:processing-instruction name="xml-multiple"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template
        match="*[x:ProductDescription]|*[x:IndustryCode]|*[x:ProductAttribute]|*[x:SaleItem]|*[x:SaleItemAttribute]|*[x:SaleItemfile]|*[x:SaleItemPrice]" >
        <xsl:processing-instruction name="xml-multiple"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Replace "item" with its parent in source XML -->
    <xsl:template
         match="x:ProductDescription|x:IndustryCode|x:ProductAttribute|x:SaleItem|x:SaleItemAttribute|x:SaleItemfile|x:SaleItemPrice">
        <xsl:element name="{name(..)}" namespace="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```